# Getting started with encryption in Objective-C/iOS

Tags: ios, security, encryption, cryptography

I'm starting to learn more about public and private keys with encryption and how security and encryption works. I have been looking on Google for good tutorials about how to secure data and build encryption into iOS applications. Does anyone know of any good open source APIs/code or tutorials that have examples for iOS encryption? Specifically I'm looking to figure out a way to be able to encrypt data send the encrypted data to another device or service and be able to decode that data.

I was looking at [this Github repo](https://github.com/ideawu/Objective-C-RSA) and under the usage section it shows example of how to encrypt a string with the public key. How would one go about generating that key to be able to encrypt the data?

Any getting started pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only lib I know where something can be encrypted in iOS and decrypted in PHP is [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

But if you only want to encrypt/decrypt NSData, you can use: [ATAESEncryption](https://github.com/apptality/ATAESEncryption)

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to generate key pairs on iOS tho? If so any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: No I dont sorry, you should google or github. Or search on ManiacDev.com :)